# Xcode building become very slow on "sign my.app" stage

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode become very slow on "sign my.app" stage in my routine work. My project contain Objective-C and Swift. I have tried clean, re-launched and delete derived data but nothing happened.

Typically this stage will cost 200~300 seconds in every building action. It has a bad impact on my efficiency. Why this happened and how to resolve it?

Any advise is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Cleaned? Quit & re-launched? Cleared derived data?

Comment: I have tried clean, re-launched and delete derived data. Nothing happened.

Comment: I would say report this as a bug to Apple. Revert to legacy build system for now if that helps.

Comment: OK, thanks. Try to revert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found there are many duplicated certificate in my keychain, Because I install one certificate too many times.

When I remove all duplicated certificate in keychain just keep first one, The sign stage become as fast as before.

[image]